# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 on a netbook with a 160G Hard Drive. If I want to change to Ubuntu 12.04, there are 3 options:

1. Upgrade to 12.04
2. Erase Hard Disk and make a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04
3. Install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Ubuntu 10.04 on a new partition

I'm very happy with Ubuntu 10.04 and I don't want dump it, so I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Ubuntu 10.04 creating 80 GB of free space on hard disk and installing it just there. Will GRUB show both Ubuntu 10.04 and Ubuntu 12.04 or only one when I boot up the netbook?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, You can install a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04 along side with ubuntu 10.04(current).You just need to mention a separate parition for root of 12.04 and a common swap with your current operating system. And yeah, grub will recognise both ubuntu as separate versions and will open each of them as separate operating system. Only problem I could encouter was the login problems. If you do have that problems, then post it later.